# Why did the computer win?

Tags: rules, winning

I just played chess on my mac and the computer (black) won. Here's the final board:

[image: Final board]

Why couldn't I, white, use my king (D4) to take the black queen (C5)?

Comment: just look at the rules of chess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the queen is protected by the bishop on A3. Therefore its checkmate.

Comment: That's a knight, not a bishop.

Comment: Oh hang on, maybe you're right. It could just be unclear graphics. I thought it was a knight, but looking closer I guess it might be a bishop.

Comment: @alex That's actually a bishop, just compare it to the knight on H3.

Comment: Good spotting. I'll change the board to a clearer one. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a pawn on a3 :) Cool 3D board, by the way.

Comment: @RauanSagit We can tell it's not a pawn by comparing it to the other black pawns on the board. Out of context the peice on A3 would be rather ambiguous but given the context we have from other peices on the board it's pretty clear it must be a bishop.